# degrading performance with gunicorn

Tags: multithreading, performance, memory-leaks, multiprocessing, gunicorn

We have a dockerised python-flask-gunicorn app with below gunicorn config.
The python app uses multiprocessing module within itself.
There is also timeout = 10 defined to kill workers running a request for more than 10s
the worker class we use is sync

```
workers = os.getenv("WORKERS")
worker_class = os.getenv("WORKER_CLASS") if os.getenv("WORKER_CLASS") else "sync"
threads = os.getenv("THREADS") if os.getenv("THREADS") else 1
timeout = 10
max_requests = 1000
max_requests_jitter = 500
preload_app = True
```

Problem is that whatever combination of workers and threads counts we specify, we have below behavior.

When we deploy the container and run a load test, the first tests runs fine.
After some time, the second test is triggered and it performs worse.
We see an increased number of gunicorn processes, even more than specified in config (threads*workers).
With each test we see an increase in the number of gunicorn processes.
This might be the reason in the decreased performance test-over-test.

Note that there is also increase in number of times-out requests with each test (taking more than 10s)
Can anyone please suggest if it is the case and if yes, how to have better control on the gunicorn processes and the memory it holds.

We already tried many combinations of worker and thread count but its same each time

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that there was nothing much to be done in gunicorn ,and there was some possible improvement in the part of code using the python ProcessPoolExecutor :

Using the "max_tasks_per_child" and setting it to 500 restarted the process and it released any memory it held.
This improved the memory usage a lot.

As per docs:
"max_tasks_per_child is an optional argument that specifies the maximum number of tasks a single process can execute before it will exit and be replaced with a fresh worker process."